# Highstock X-Axis: Relative time instead of absolute time

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How do I show relative time on the x-axis in a Highstocks chart?

My goal is to have the x-axis use constant labels such as "1 month", "1 year", "3 year" and the points placed according to today.

For example, if I have a point who's x value is 1477267200, which is 10/24/2016 in datetime (exactly a year from today), and I look at the graph today I would see it placed where the "1 year" label is, but if i look at it tomorrow it would be placed to the left of the "1 year" label.

Comment: `moment.js` is a library that can help you convert absolute dates to relative ones.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relative time in Highstocks chart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27116134/relative-time-in-highstocks-chart)

Comment: You'll need to define a starting point, and determine what the dates are at those intervals from that starting point.  You'll need an array that contains the name of those intervals.  Then you can use the 'tickPositions' property, and the label formatter to position and populate them.